# MINGW cannot find -laxtls lib when configure with curl is used

Tags: curl, openssl, mingw, libcurl, mingw32

I am running configure step in order to build cURL 7.51.10 with OpenSSL support.

```
LIBS="-ldl" ./configure --with-ssl
```

Configure fails to enable SSL because of this step

```
configure:25115: checking for ssl_version in -laxtls
configure:25137: gcc -o conftest.exe -O2 -Wno-system-headers -isystem /c/Build-OpenSSL-VC-64/include/
-isystem /g/Library/zlib-1.2.8/ -L/c//Build-OpenSSL-VC-64/lib/ -L/g/Library/zlib-1.2.8/Out/Win64/Debug/
-L/lib/ conftest.c -laxtls  -lwldap32 -lws2_32 -ldl >&5
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -laxtls
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Has anyone overcome this issue ?

Comment: You seem to have asked for axTLS to be used and not OpenSSL (indicating the command line you showed here is not the one you used). Also, always consult `config.log` after configure failures to learn more about the failed tests.